# Is there a way to use only shifts and rotates to reverse an array in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to reverse the elements of an array in assembly language, only using shifts and rotates.

Lets say, for example, I a have an array of bytes that has 5 elements:

> 01, 02, 03, 04, 05

I want it to be transformed to:

> 05, 04, 03, 02, 01

I know several other ways I could go about this, but I'm trying to do it with shifts and rotates only.

Comment: What kind of instruction set do you like to use? ARM, x86, SSE/AVX, MIPS...? BTW shifts and rotates often apply to BITs in a chunk and not chunks of BITs like BYTEs, WORDs, DWORDs...

Comment: One easy way to reverse 16 bytes with the SSE instruction set is [`PSHUFB`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSHUFB.html).

Comment: x86. And yes, I am used to using shifts and rotates with bits. If i can not shift actual elements of an array, is there a way to shift the bits to accomplish the same task?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ROL`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RCL:RCR:ROL:ROR.html) or [`ROR`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RCL:RCR:ROL:ROR.html) over WORDs with a (kind of static) [BubbleSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) algorithm swapping adjacent elements, for example.

```
EAX points to the first element of the BYTE array

01 02 03 04 05   ; ROL WORD PTR [EAX]  , 8   ==>
02 01 03 04 05   ; ROL WORD PTR [EAX+1], 8   ==>
02 03 01 04 05   ; ROL WORD PTR [EAX+2], 8   ==>
02 03 04 01 05   ; ROL WORD PTR [EAX+3], 8   ==>
02 03 04 05 01   ; ROL WORD PTR [EAX]  , 8   ==>
03 02 04 05 01   ; ROL WORD PTR [EAX+1], 8   ==>
03 04 02 05 01   ; ROL WORD PTR [EAX+2], 8   ==>
03 04 05 02 01   ; ROL WORD PTR [EAX]  , 8   ==>
04 03 05 02 01   ; ROL WORD PTR [EAX+1], 8   ==>
04 05 03 02 01   ; ROL WORD PTR [EAX]  , 8   ==>
05 04 03 02 01   ; ==> DONE!
```

I did not create a full implementation of this algorithm, but you should get the idea.